# truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape error shows while i try to compile this code

Tags: python, class, import, dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeDrP.png)

class_name='normal'                                                                       #'covid' or 'normal' or 'pneumonia'

```
source_dir="C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images"+class_name
destination_dir='C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images_preprocessed'+class_name
```

It keeps showing that error

Answer (score 0):

`source_dir="C:\\Users\\RAJDEEP\\Desktop\\FINAL\\original_images\\"+class_name`

The correct syntax. You can also try conversion to raw string

`r'C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images_preprocessed\'+class_name`